# Every fiber intersects transversally the section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, let $S$ be a smooth projective surface over $k$, let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $k$.

Let $f:S\to C$ be a *genus $1$ fibration*, i.e., $f$ is a surjective morphism with connected fibers, such that for all but finitely many $v\in C$, $f^{-1}(v)$ is a smooth curve with genus $1$. Let $\sigma:C\to S$ be a section for $f$, i.e., $f\circ \sigma=\text{id}_C$.

I would like to prove the following assertion:

> Every fibre intersects $\sigma(C)$ transversally in a single point.

The *single point* part is easy. If $v\in C$, then $\sigma\left (C\right )\cap f^{-1}(v)=\left \{ \sigma(v) \right \}$. I cannot prove that the intersection is transversal. Moreover, it should be "obvious", since I know this to be true because of these following sources:

First, if you read "Mordell-Weil Lattices" by Matthias Schütt and Tetsuji Shioda, you find it in the proof of Proposition 5.4: *The global sections of $f:S\to C$ are in a natural one-to-one correspondence with the $K$-rational points of $E$*. Here $K=k(C)$ and $E$ is the generic fiber of $f$.

The proof begins this way:

[image]

There we find the assertion (I highlighted the important part).

Moreover, if we read the article "On the Mordell-Weil Lattices" by Tetsuji Shioda, we find it as an "obvious" lemma.

[image]

How would you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p \in F \cap \sigma(C)$ be an intersection point of a fibre and a section. Let $c \in C$ be the unique point such that $\sigma(c)=p$.

The equation $f \circ \sigma = \operatorname{id}_C$ then gives

$$ df_p \circ d \sigma_c = \operatorname{id}_{T_c C}$$

which shows that $df_p$ is injective on the subspace $d \sigma_c(T_c C) = T_p (\sigma(C))$. On the other hand, $\operatorname{ker} df_p$ contains $T_pF$ since $f$ is constant on $F$. So this shows that
$$ T_pF \cap T_p (\sigma(C)) = \{0\};$$
in other words the intersection is transversal.

Comment: Thank you! I have a subtle question: when you say that $d\sigma_c(T_cC)=T_p(\sigma(C))$, are you assuming that $\sigma$ is non-singular at $p$? Because, if it is not, then it is not clear even if these two spaces have the same dimension, for $T_p(\sigma (C)))$ could have dimension higher than $1$. If so, is there any a priori way to prove that $\sigma(C)$ is non-singular?

Comment: The missing detail is that $\sigma$ is an embedding of $C$ in $F$, so it is an isomorphism onto its image. That follows for example by the characterisation of embeddings as maps that separate points and tangent vectors, and using the identity $f \circ \sigma = \operatorname{id}_C$ and its derivative to see that $\sigma$ satisfies both conditions.